# Creating XML with numeric strings

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I'm creating an XML document from an array of NSDictionarys as follows:

```
for (NSDictionary *info in sorted) 
{
    NSArray *item = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
        [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"name" stringValue: [info objectForKey: @"Name"]],                  
        [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"year" stringValue: [info objectForKey: @"Year"]],                  
                          nil];

         node = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"item" children: item attributes:nil];
         [root addChild:node];
}   
NSData *xmlData = [xmlDoc XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
```

I then write out the NSData object.  That all works fine.

The problem is that the values for the "year" entity are being converted to scientific notation.  That is, if the original string in the info dictionary is "1998", what ends up in the XML file is:

```
    <year>1.998E3</year>
```

I tried putting quotes around the string when adding the element, but then I get quotes in the output XML:

```
    <year>"1998"</year>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is sorted and how is data added here.

Comment: The original data for sorted was read from an XML file.  Maybe that dictionary wasn't all string objects.

Comment: The issue is what type does [info objectForKey: return as that is what is printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's documentation for setObjectValue in [NSXMLNode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSXMLElementKind) is suggestive:

Note: Prior to Mac OS X v 10.6 setObjectValue: would improperly and inconsistently format objects that were NSNumber instances. Applications linked on Mac OS X 10.6 or later will use correct scientific notation for all NSNumbers passed to setObjectValue:.
If you require a particular format for any value in your XML document, you should format the data yourself as a string and then use setStringValue: to set the value. This guarantees that the text generated is in a format you control directly.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe I actually did have NSNumbers in that dictionary, and not NSStrings.  For that field, anyway.  I was parsing another XML file and I thought I was getting back all NSStrings.